# I would like to find all the psalms that include my name

Tags: tanach, tehilim-psalms

Can someone please give me a list of all psalms or pesukim that include my name. my hebrew name is רִנָּה

Comment: Do you know what a concordance is?

Answer (score 3):

Isaiah: 14:7, 44:23, 48:20, 49:13, 54:1, 55:12

Jeremiah: 7:16, 11:14

Psalms: 30:6, 42:5, 47:2, 118:15, 126:2

Proverbs: 11:10

Comment: Curious...what database did you use to find these?

Comment: I went to the Bar Ilan responsa and searched for Rinah (no prefixes/suffixes) and got 14 results. Otherwise, I would have gone to the Even Shoshan and just counted.